# Query never returns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple LINQ-to-EF query that for some reason stopped working, by which I mean that as soon as it is executed, execution control is never returned to the next line.  I can't figure out why that may be the case.  if I run the same query in LinqPad using LINQ-to-SQL, it works fine.  here's the query:

```
Models.Currency curr = _db.Currencies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ISO == p.Items[i].CurrType);
```

where `_db` is my entity container reference and `p.Items[i].CurrType` contains the value "USD"

what could be the problem? what kind of diagnostics could I make use of?

TIA - e!

p.s. I'm running on Visual Studio 2013 with MVC5

*** update I ***

as per the suggestions below, I added both a "Connection Timeout=10" to my connection string (in the Web.config) and a command timeout (in the *.Context.cs) like this:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 10;
    }
```

the query still hangs (never times out to throw an exception) and I had a gander at the database whilst the query was hung.  I can see that the SQL issued looks (more or less) like:

```
select * from Currencies
```

which should return immediately since there are only 100 small records in that table.  the connection on which the query gets issued is sleeping and awaiting command, and there is no blocking in the database; the spid in question performed 0 cpu/io.

what else should I be looking at?

Comment: Check if the timeout happens on connection. This happened to me the issue was in connection string and that's why it was taking some time to return the control. It was throwing exception after timeout of connection.

Comment: Do you have a timeout specified on your db context? 
I'd be tempted to look at SQL Profiler to ensure that your query is making it to the database and see if it provides any insight as to why it is failing to return (deadlock??)

Comment: Did  "Models.Currency curr = _db.Currencies.FirstOrDefault()"  execute correctly? In my case, I had to much items in db and query takes just to long.  p.s. you should profile data base with profiler and check what query is going to db.

Comment: Are you getting an exception while trying to execute that line, or is the thread just stuck on that line forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a little help from suchiman at freenode's c# channel revealed the problem: I should have been seeing an exception bubble up but I wasn't.  he recommended I log my database output like this:

```
_db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

that revealed the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Closed connection at 3/17/2015 3:56:43 PM -07:00

from which he cleverly deduced that the reference to `p.Items[i].CurrType` was messing linq up.  here's his reasoning:

> ```
> [Suchiman] Items[i] is actually a method call
> [Suchiman] get_Items(i)
> [Suchiman] transformed by the compiler
> [Suchiman] when analyzing the expression tree, EF will realize 
> [Suchiman] there's a method called get_Items(Int32)
> [Suchiman] but it doesn't have any clue how to translate this into SQL
> [Suchiman] thats why it throws NotSupportedException
> ```

which is proven by the fact that if I rewrite the code like this:

```
var item = p.Items[i];
var curr = _db.Currencies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ISO == item.CurrType);
```

it works!